# Python 3: Почему print(0o11) будет 9?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему в Python3 `print(0o11)` будет 9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что это [восьмеричная система счисления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Если переводить в десятичную, то будет `0o11 = 1*(8**1) + 1*(8**0) = 8 + 1 = 9`.

Comment: а буква 'o' что означает?

Comment: @Ilnyr, "octal" (собственно, "восьмеричный")